# Ruby Stabby Lambda can receive arguments?

Tags: ruby, lambda

I can define a lambda like that and it works:

```rb
greet = lambda { |name| puts "Hello, #{name}" }
  
greet.call "João"
=> Hello, João.
```

This works:

```rb
lamb = -> { puts 'Lambdas are tricky' }
lamb.call
=> Lambdas are tricky
```

But I wonder if it's possible to pass arguments using the stabby lambda `->`

Unsuccessful attempts:

```rb
greet = (name) -> { puts "Hello, #{name}" }
greet = -> { |name| puts "Hello, #{name}" }
```

Comment: It would be interesting to know what, *specifically* is unclear to you about the documentation. That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation, so that future developers don't stumble over the same problems as you did.

Comment: See the docs for [Literals > Procs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Procs) or [Proc > Creation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Proc.html#class-Proc-label-Creation)

Comment: I was using devdocs.io and I couldn't find it there... Now i'll double check the offical docs.
https://devdocs.io/ruby~2.6/proc#method-i-lambda-3F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can absolutely pass arguments to a stabby lambda. You just write it as if you're passing arguments to a method that expects a block. For example:

```
greet = ->(name) { p "Hello, #{name}!" }
greet.call "world"
#=> "Hello, world!"
```

You can also accept multiple arguments this way. Consider:

```
prc = ->(foo, bar) { p "foo: #{foo}, bar: #{bar}" }
prc.call "baz", "quux"
#=> "foo: baz, bar: quux"
```

Comment: ohhh all I should to do was change the order between the stabby and the params... now I see haha. many thanks!